# Kubernetes Controller is not able to detect events for the resources register with owner references as the same controller object

Tags: kubernetes, controller, operator-keyword, watch

I am working on a custom kubernetes controller, which creates kubernetes secrets based off some inputs. As part of this controller it is required to copy these secrets to multiple namespaces. Which it successfully does.

For e.g.

```
CustomSecretGenerator 

metadata:
 names : mypersonalsecret
spec:
 secret:
  name: mysecret
  namespace: default
 target:
  namespaces:
   - dev
   - personal
```

Above is a rough CRD of the controller input. I am able to copy secrets from one namespace to another with owner reference set to my Controller name.

My PROBLEM:

1. If I delete the default/mysecret secret it will auto-generate (with a autogenerating logic). But if I delete secret in other namespaces i.e. dev/mysecret or personal/mysecret the controller doesnt auto-generate (with the autogenerating logic). I tried to catch all the events, but I suspect that Controller is not able to watch the secret generated in the target namespace.

Here is watch code block

```
err = c.Watch(&source.Kind{Type: &corev1.Secret{}}, &handler.EnqueueRequestForOwner{
        IsController: true,
        OwnerType:    &appv1alpha1.MyCustomController{},
    })
```

and this is the metadata section for all the secrets that get generated with the controller

```
name: mysecret
  namespace: dev
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: com.company.app/v1alpha1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: MyCustomController
    name: example-customer-controller
    uid: ed2fa8c5-6855-11e9-94c6-0050569d445e
```

Also my controller is running in a default namespace and has role with all access to secrets.

**EDIT:**

This is the section of the code which creates the Secret.

```
mySecret := &corev1.Secret{
        TypeMeta: meta_v1.TypeMeta{
            APIVersion: "v1",
            Kind:       "Secret",
        },
        ObjectMeta: meta_v1.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      secretName,
            Namespace: secretNamespace,
            Labels:    labelsforRegistryToken(crt.Name),
        },
        Data: map[string][]byte{
            v1.DockerConfigJsonKey: jsonValue,
        },
        Type: corev1.SecretTypeDockerConfigJson,
    }
    controllerutil.SetControllerReference(crt, mySecret, r.scheme)
```

NOTE: `crt` is the custom controller object which controls the creation of the object.

I tried copying the ownerrefence from the default/mysecret to dev/mysecret, the controller is still not able to detect the deletion of the dev/mysecret.

Comment: You are using handler.EnqueueRequestForOwner. Are you sure that you are correctly setting the owner of the secrets the controller creates ? Could you post that code section ?

Comment: @MiguelGarcia updated the question with the code which sets the owner reference to the secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the controller wasn't able to detect the changes from the object in other namespace, I tried to scan all the namespaces in the cluster and had the reconcile loop end with

`return reconcile.Result{RequeueAfter: time.Duration(15) * time.Minute}, nil`

to allow reconciliation every 15 minutes. The controller does respond to the events to the secrets created in the same namespace as the controller is running.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add Owner References to the generated secrets like this.

```
func setOwnerRef(secret *corev1.Secret)error{
  ownerRef := generateOwneRef(secret)
  secret.SetOwnerRefrences(ownerRef)
  return nil
}

func generateOwnerRef(secret *corev1.Secret) []metav1.OwnerReference {
    return []metav1.OwnerReference{
        *metav1.NewControllerRef(secret, schema.GroupVersionKind{
            Group:   appv1alpha1.SchemeGroupVersion.Group,
            Version: appv1alpha1.SchemeGroupVersion.Version,
            Kind:    constants.ObjectKind,
        }),
    }
}
```

and then you check for owner reference type.

Comment: The function you are calling on line 3 is `SetOwnerReferences()` I assume.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem though! I can see that the ownerreferences of the secrets in default and dev namespaces are same, yet the controller cannot detect the events for the secrets in the namespaces other than default.

Comment: did you checked RBAC roles for controller ?

Comment: Yes I tried giving * access to secrets, namespaces and other resources like pods etc.